# Extjs - drag drop restriction, containment

Tags: extjs, drag-and-drop

In Extjs, I want to know whether I can restrict the dragging of elements within a specific x,y co-ordinates, just like an option, containment in jQuery-UI.

Currently this is my code:

```
abc.prototype.initDrag = function(v) {
    v.dragZone = new Ext.dd.DragZone(v.getEl(), {
                containerScroll : false,
                getDragData : function(e) {
                    var sourceEl = e.getTarget(v.itemSelector, 10);
                    var t = e.getTarget();
                    var rowIndex = abc.grid.getView().findRowIndex(t);
                    var columnIndex = abc.grid.getView().findCellIndex(t);
                    var abcDragZone = v.dragZone ; //Ext.getCmp('idabcDragZone');
                    var widthToScrollV = $(window).width()-((columnIndex-1)*100);
                    var widthToScrollH = $(window).height()-((5-rowIndex)*30);
                    abcDragZone.setXConstraint(0,widthToScrollV);
                    abcDragZone.setYConstraint(widthToScrollH,0);
                    if ((rowIndex !== false) && (columnIndex !== false)) {
                        if (sourceEl) {
                            abc.isDragged = true;
                            def.scriptGrid.isDraggableForObject = false;
                            def.scriptGrid.dragRowIndex = false;
                            d = sourceEl.cloneNode(true);
                            d.id = Ext.id();
                            d.textContent = "\$" + abc.grid.getColumnModel().getColumnHeader(columnIndex);
                            return {
                                ddel : d,
                                sourceEl : d,
                                sourceStore : v.store
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                getRepairXY : function() {
                    return this.dragData.repairXY;
                },
            });    
}
```

But the problem is that the initdrag is called when the csv sheet is added to DOM. Only when its added that element can be accessed and the individual cells' drag limits can be set. So once I add a csv, the limits are not getting set. If I add it again to DOM then the limits work. Is there an option like the jQuery UI containment for draggable, here in extjs?

edit:
I even tried :

```
constrainTo( constrainTo, [pad], [inContent] )
```

body had an id of #abc
when I tried with

```
dragZoneObj.startDrag = function(){
                                this.constrainTo('abc');
                            };
```

which is a method of the DragZone class. It still did not cover the whole body tag.